# Confusion over shallow copies of arrays in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, parameters, parameter-passing, shallow-copy

My understanding is that a shallow copy of an array copies the array variable, so that you have two pointers to the same memory location on the heap. But according to that logic, the following piece of code should work, but it doesn't:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim row As Long() = {1, 2, 3, 4}
    ChangeRow(row.Clone)
    Console.WriteLine(row(0))
End Sub

Sub ChangeRow(ByVal array As Long())
    array(0) = 0
End Sub
```

The Clone method supposedly makes a shallow copy. That would mean that you pass a pointer to the original array as a parameter. Everything I've read on the topic so far points to this piece of code working, but it doesn't. Can anyone explain?

The dialect in question is VB.Net

Comment: Please clarify what dialect this is, VB.NET, VB6, VBA, etc.

Comment: The dialect is VB.Net

Comment: So the most important tag is missing...

Comment: @trincot Sorry, it's been a long day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My understanding is that a shallow copy of an array copies the array variable, so that you have two pointers to the same memory location on the heap.

No. It creates a **new** container, containing all the same items and otherwise identical to the previous container, but the containers themselves reside in different locations on the heap. It does not create a duplicate reference to the previous container.

What you're describing is just a reference. Consider this code:

```
Dim row As Long() = {1, 2, 3, 4}
Dim otherRow as Long() = row
```

The program's memory now looks a little like this:

[image: reference]

[`Clone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.clone?view=netframework-4.7.2) will indeed create a shallow copy—that is, it will create a **new** array that contains all the same values as the original array. Then, you set the value at the first item on that new array, but this will have no affect on the original, because these are completely different arrays with no run-time reference to each other. Consider this code:

```
Dim row As Long() = {1, 2, 3, 4}
Dim otherRow as Long() = row.Clone
```

The program's memory now looks a little like this:

[image: clone]

If you want to modify the original array within the `ChangeRow` subroutine, simply don't call clone.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim row As Long() = {1, 2, 3, 4}
    ChangeRow(row)
    Console.WriteLine(row(0)) ' outputs 0
End Sub

Sub ChangeRow(ByVal array As Long())
    array(0) = 0
End Sub
```

To illustrate why this is actually a 'shallow' copy, examine how this works with reference types.

```
Class Ref
    Public Value As Long 
    Public Sub New(ByVal value As Long)
        Value = value
    End Sub
End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim row As Ref() = {New Ref(1), New Ref(2), New Ref(3), New Ref(4)}
    ChangeRow(row.Clone)
    Console.WriteLine(row(0).Value) ' outputs 0
End Sub

Sub ChangeRow(ByVal array As Ref())
    array(0).Value = 0
End Sub
```

Even though `row` and `row.Clone` refer to different arrays, the values in those arrays (the instances of `Ref`) are the same, so modifying `array(0).Value` is the same as modifying `row(0).Value`. In this case, the program's memory looks a little like this:

[image: shallow copy]

Comment: Does that mean that as long as the values contained in an array aren't reference types themselves, Cloning will create and independent copy, whereas deep copying will create an independent data set no matter if the data contained in the array is reference type or not?

Comment: Yes. Generally speaking, the term "shallow copy" refers to only duplicating a memory structure only one level deep, whereas the term "deep copy" refers to duplicating a memory structure to an arbitrary depth. If your array only contains value types, then yes, the structure only goes down one level--you can't go any deeper.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. The course material is extremely vague and unhelpful on this topic.

Comment: I'm absolutely amazed by how well you have illustrated this! Excellent answer!

Comment: @VisualVincent I suppose that's high praise from someone called *Visual* Vincent. It's literally just MS Paint though. :)

Comment: Hahaha, contrary to what my name (or _alias_, more correctly) suggests, I'm only decent when it comes to design ;). It was actually a friend of mine who came up with the name Visual Vincent, since I programmed a lot in _Visual Studio_ at the time (and still do).

Comment: Though you don't need to be an artist or use expensive programs to do a great job! In this case it's how you deliver "the message" that matters, which I was amazed that you managed to do so perfectly! Everyone can draw a painting, but not everyone can make it so informative with so little in it!